# How to write mysql query with WHERE 1 in Codeigniter Active record form

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to write the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE_NAME` WHERE 1
```

in codeigniter Active record form ?

I tried something like:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('TABLE_NAME');
$this->db->where('1');
```

But I am getting the following error:

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '1' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT * FROM (`TABLE_NAME`) WHERE `1` IS NULL
```

I am using same method for selecting values from database. I just pass the columns, condition and table name. My problem is, when I want to get all the data from a table, what will I give in the where clause ?

Following is my query section:

```
function get($fields,$table,$where)
{
     $this->db->select($fields);
     $this->db->from($table);
     $this->db->where($where); 
     $q = $this->db->get();
     if($q->num_rows() > 0)
     {
         foreach($q->result() as $row)
         {
              $data[] = $row;
         } 
         return $data; 
      }
 }
```

Following how I call the function in controller:

```
$data['details'] = $this->MODEL_NAME->get("*",PREFIX."TABLE_NAME",1);
```

The model here is loaded from autoload.

Comment: whats the column name ?

Comment: The sql is wrong. should be something like SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Mexico';

Comment: `SELECT * FROM t WHERE 1` is equivalent to `SELECT * FROM t` in DBMS where `1` means `true`. Why do you specifically need the `WHERE 1` bit?

Comment: @Amadan I have edited my question: I am using same method for selecting values from database. I just pass the columns, condition and table name. My problem is, when I want to get all the data from a table, what will I give in the where clause ?

Comment: "My problem is, when I want to get all the data from a table, what will I give in the where clause ?" Nothing; don't give a `WHERE` clause. `WHERE` is used to *restrict* the dataset - you don't want to restrict it, just don't restrict it.

Comment: @Amadan Can you check my code now. Again I have edited my question.

Comment: Post also controller code!!

Comment: @Amadan i missing **no** in my comment !! my mistake

Comment: I have edited my codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$this->db->where($where);
```

into

```
if ($where !== null) {
    $this->db->where($where);
}
```

and

```
function get($fields,$table,$where)
```

into

```
function get($fields,$table,$where=null)
```

so you can opt not to give `$where` when you call `get`.